# Special Triangles and their related acute angles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

So I've been working on some questions involving having to find the exact value of trig. functions involving a particular interval.  I have worked through the question but now I have something I am not sure about.  The question was $2\cos^2x+\cos x-1=0$.

I began by factoring the question using the quadratic formula and got $x=1/2$ and $x=-1$.  To solve the first equation $\cos x=1/2$, I need to figure out by drawing the correct special triangle using $\pi/3$ as my acute angle if $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$.  I hope I have worded this correctly, please correct me if I am wrong.  For this I know that $\cos=\text{adjacent/hypotenuse}$ will be the key to this.  If someone could clarify my answer that would be great!

Comment: It's correct that $\cos x = -1 , 0.5$ are the solutions of the equation. But it's not clear what you want. Do you want to solve $\cos x  =0.5$ and $\cos x = -1$ by drawing triangles?

Comment: Yes, my appologies.  Basically after factoring, you have to solve the two separate equations (isolate for x) and then determine what it's related acute angle would be.

Comment: so what would the related acute angle of cosx=1/2 and cosx=-1 be?

Comment: $\cos \pi/3 = 0.5$ and $\cos \pi = -1$. In second case, you cannot draw a triangle, because the angle is not acute.

Comment: So is in the cospi=-1, would you determine this by simply looking at the unit cirlce? Because since it is a negative value it would have to be in either quadrant 2 or 3.  Noted on the x-axis of the unit cirlce, the value furthest to the left (that is shown) is pi.

Comment: Take a unit circle and put a point somewhere on its circumference. Now draw a vertical line from the point to x-axis. Draw another line from the point to the center of the circle. This gives you a triangle. Now move the point around the circle. When $x = 0,\pi,2\pi$ the triangle becomes a line (along $x$-axis).

Comment: Hmm, okay.  I will use this to see how I progress with the rest of the question.  Would I be able to ask you to clarify my answer when I am finished?

Comment: For the entire question it is to find the exact values of x such that 0< or = x < or =2pi. The question I asked was just to make sure that I get the related acute angles properly.

Comment: I will post my comments as an answer and edit that properly later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $2\cos^2x+\cos x-1=0$ has two solutions $\cos x = -1 , 0.5$ since:

$$
2\cos^2x+\cos x-1=0 = (\cos x - \frac{1}{2} )(\cos x+1)
$$

Therefore we have two equation to solve:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos x &=& -1 \\
\cos x &=& \frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now draw a unit circle and put a point somewhere on its circumference. Then draw a vertical line from the point to $x$-axis. Draw another line from the point to the center of the circle. This gives you a triangle. Now move the point around the circle. When $x=0,π,2π$ the triangle becomes a line (along $x$-axis). In fact:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos x &=& -1 \Rightarrow x = \pi \\
\cos x &=& \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow x = \frac{\pi}{3}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Okay, great thankyou!

Comment: If you think this answers your question, please accept this answer(click on the check mark below the upvote/downvote on the left top corner).